# Microsoft Teams - Deeplink to Bot app tab removes the "Chat" option from App

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to create a deeplink to a tab for my MS teams app, the deeplink works like https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<APP_ID>/<TAB_ENTITY_ID>. I am using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-your-tab) for generating the deeplink.

I am opening the deeplink through an adaptive card button from the bot conversation. The deeplink redirects me to the tab successfully but it removes the chat option. But, on refreshing the same link, the chat tab reappears.

Answer (score 1):

@Pallavi, This is known issue and getting fixed. Soon fix will be available in GA.

Comment: what is the ETA for the fix? I'm asking because I'm building an application that suffers from the same issue which can delay our release :(

Comment: @Frederick, Cannot provide eta for this. This will be shipped soon.

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT I am facing the same issue. This is urgent for us as well

Comment: @Gags - Currently this is under development. Should out soon.

Comment: @Gags, There is not ETA that I can provide you on this.

Comment: I had the same issue, but it seems it has been solved a few weeks ago without any changes to my code or configuration.

Comment: @Abhijit I observed that this issue has been resolved now.