# MS Teams - Deep Link in Bot Removes Chat Tab

Tags: chatbot, deep-linking, microsoft-teams

I took help of the following documentation to open a tab from a Chat Bot within my MS Teams using Deep Linking. Note: My MS Teams App is Bot + Tab

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links
```

Deep Link Used:
[https://teams.microsoft.com/l%2Fentity%2F9eb33c56-6321-4da8-934f-9ba5a620157c%2FVSPPortal%3Fveeam%26label%3DVSP%2520Portal%2520%26context%3D%257B%2522subEntityId%2522%3A%2520%2522alerts%2522%257D](https://teams.microsoft.com/l%2Fentity%2F9eb33c56-6321-4da8-934f-9ba5a620157c%2FVSPPortal%3Fveeam%26label%3DVSP%20Portal%20%26context%3D%7B%22subEntityId%22%3A%20%22alerts%22%7D)

I used the following in my Adaptive Card:

```
"actions": [
      {
          "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
          "title": "Continuity Planner Tab",
          "url": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l%2Fentity%2F9eb33c56-6321-4da8-934f-9ba5a620157c%2FVSPPortal%3Fveeam%26label%3DVSP%2520Portal%2520%26context%3D%257B%2522subEntityId%2522%3A%2520%2522alerts%2522%257D"
      },
```

My MS Teams App initially shows  4 tabs - **Chat, Tab1, Tab2 , About**

When I click the Deep Link button in Adaptive Card in Bot it takes me to Tab2. (Accepted Behavior)
However, the first tab i.e. Chat disappears.

After Navigating via Deep Link App shows 3 tabs - **Tab1, Tab2, About**

How do I keep the first tab i.e. Chat visible.
Please help.

Thanks,
Gagan

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue and getting fixed. Soon fix will be available in GA as per below link:

[Microsoft Teams - Deeplink to Bot app tab removes the "Chat" option from App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64367615/microsoft-teams-deeplink-to-bot-app-tab-removes-the-chat-option-from-app)